# Why is there a line between my linked images

Tags: html, css

There is a thin horizontal line between my linked images, I'm not sure what could be causing this or how to fix it. Any ideas?

```css
.hvr-bounce-to-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  margin: 20px;
}
.cowalign {
  text-align: center;
}
.cowalign img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 350px;
}
.imgDescription {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 286px;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  /*remove comment if you want a gradual transition between states
      -webkit-transition: visibility opacity 0.2s;
      */
}
.bgcolor {
  max-width: 1300px;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  margin: auto;
}
.container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 3%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.logowordmark img {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
#navigation {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 40px
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #999999;
}
.heading {
  clear: both;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 750px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#ourwork {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.titlework {
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.descriptionwork {
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #21A4B9;
}
#ourwork span {
  color: #21A4B9;
}
#ourworksubtext {
  color: #999999;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover .imgDescription {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #2D2D2D;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  opacity: 0.95;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-bounce-to-right:hover:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:focus:before,
.hvr-bounce-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 1.64, 0.37, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<div class="cowalign">

  <a href="#">
    <div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
      <div class="imgWrap">
        <div class="imgDescription"><span class="titlework">Deadeye BBQ</span>
          <br>
          <span class="descriptionwork">Website/Mobile/Poster Design</span>
        </div>
        <img src="images/001-MacBook-Silverlarge.jpg" alt="cow">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>



  <a href="#">
    <div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
      <div class="imgWrap">
        <div class="imgDescription"><span class="titlework">Jellyfish Evening</span>
          <br>
          <span class="descriptionwork"> Poster Design</span>
        </div>
        <img src="images/jellyfishevening.jpg" alt="cow">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>


  <div class="cowalign">


    <div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
      <div class="imgWrap">
        <div class="imgDescription"><span class="titlework">Aerial Aid</span>
          <br>
          <span class="descriptionwork"> Logo Design</span>
        </div>
        <img src="images/aalogowork.jpg" alt="cow">
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="hvr-bounce-to-right">
      <div class="imgWrap">
        <div class="imgDescription"><span class="titlework">Dead, Dumb Fish</span>
          <br>
          <span class="descriptionwork">Poster Design</span>
        </div>
        <img src="images/fishwork.jpg" alt="cow">
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: it will be really convenient if you can make a jsfiddle to demo the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't taken away the styling for the `<a>`wrapping the elements. Hence the default underline for the `<a>`is showing. The `<a>` directly after `<div class="cowalign">`

Add something like `.cowalign a { text-decoration: none; }` in the CSS

Comment: so should I just use 
a {
style:none;
}

Comment: `a { text-decoration: none; }` to be precise

Comment: sorry a {
text-decoration:none;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
.cowalign a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It's good practice to also explain *why* a solution works. In addition, your answer has been posted already.